# How to create a page that can be accessed by either authenticated users and non authenticated

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to understand how to create a page that can be accessed by both authenticated users and non authenticated. The authenticated users will have a different header (and maybe a different master page), with links to user profile .. etc.

If I create a new masterpage for non-registered users, how can I configure laravel 5.2 to show this masterpage only if the user was not registered? Is it on the route level ?

I have the following route for my signup page :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home')->middleware('guest');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show same page to all users which has different headers depending auth you can use blade directive in your `.blade.php` file:

```php
@auth
    @include('here include auth header file')
@endauth

@guest
    @include('here include guest header file')
@endguest
```

And also do not use `auth` or `guest` middleware, which will limit access to authenticated or non authenticated users

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home'); // ->middleware('guest');
```